# Good technique for connections with PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, theory

I am using `Npgsql` to access PostgreSQL via .NET. I am concerned about the right way to perform connections to the database, since in my opinion this is an expensive operation to open a connection and then close it every single time I want to perform some transaction.

So here is the general idea:

```
public class PostgreSQL
{
    private NpgsqlConnection conn; // <- one connection for this object, open all the time

    public PostgreSQL(string connString)
    {
        conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
    }

    // ...here making some queries...

    public void Close() => conn.Close(); // <- use this in the very end of the program
}
```

As you can see above, I have one connection for an instance of `PostgreSQL` class.

**My question**:

Is this approach right? Or should I open and close connection every single time I want to make a transaction - open as late as possible and close as soon as possible?

If I should open and close connections every single time - should I write a queue that would limit the amount of concurrent connections? Or PostgreSQL will handle it itself - and, theoretically, I can open 200 connections and it will be alright.

Please share your experience with me ^^

**EDIT:**
I will run 100-200 queries a second.

Comment: You probably should add how often do you want to query the database.

Comment: @JakubKania Just added it, 100-200 queries a second.

Comment: `Npgsql` has built-in connection pooling, so however you do the queries the connections will not be completely closed and opened even though you call `Close()` and `Open()`. But is it a desktop application? Are the queries concurrent?

Comment: Have you run any performance traces to see if this is actually a problem? Most providers do connection pooling. You may starve the pool if your usage is not synchronous, but you should always do proper performance tests instead of assuming that one way is better than another way. By default I tend to open late and close early, and I've never noticed this code appear in hot tracks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion you should open a connection at the moment you need it, and close it right after it. This will prevent a lot of connections on the server to be kept alive.

In my experience, opening a connection doesn't take that much time (a few milliseconds, usually a fraction of your execution time), so you don't have to worry too much.

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL supports connections pooling (pool size is [customizable](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/User-Manual)) so the common pattern:

```
using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(...))
{
...
}
```

should be the better choice.